# VBA Excel - FileFilter prevents Workbooks.Open

Tags: excel, vba

when I am using FilterFilter in `Application.GetAsFileName()`, then I cant open the file in `set WbDatei3 = Workbooks.Open(strName)`. But when I left it, it works. Nevertheless it has to be in there, because it has to be an Excel-data. Have anyone a solution?

```
Dim strPath As String
Dim strName As String

UserForm1.Show

strPath = "C:\Desktop\"
strName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=strPath, FileFilter:="XLSX-File (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=strName

Dim WbDatei1 As Workbook
Dim WbDatei3 As Workbook

Set WbDatei1 = ThisWorkbook
Set WbDatei3 = Workbooks.Open(strName)

For Each shp In WbDatei3.Sheets(1).Shapes
shp.Delete
Next
WbDatei3.Save

WbDatei1.Activate
WbDatei1.Sheets(1).Select
Selection.Columns("F:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Comment: I meant FileFilter in the headline, sorry

Comment: What is the error you get? I tried the three lines where you have the GetSaveAs... and it works, but it corrupted by Excel file. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Does the workbook you are saving have code in it? You cannot change the file type when using `SaveCopyAs`.